# Google Finance formula in Google Sheets sometimes results in N/A until refreshed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

As the title states, my formula results in N/A randomly until refreshed. This is a problem because I have multiple formulas that are dependent on this one googlefinance() formula, as well as automatons running that pull information from google sheets, including the googlefinance() exchange rate and it's dependent formulas.

N/A can show randomly on new or even previous entries (entries that were fine days/weeks ago), and a lot of the time you will see more than one N/A result grouped together across multiple rows until refreshed. After a refresh, everything works fine...

I am not sure if this is because of google finance or because of my formula... Either way I would appreciate some guidance!

**FORMULA:**

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDAUD", "price", WORKDAY(R761+1,-1),1),2,2)
```

**ALSO TRIED:**

```
=iferror(iferror(INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDAUD", "price", WORKDAY(R761+1,-1),1),2,2),INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDAUD", "price", WORKDAY(R761+1,-1),1),2,2)),INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDAUD", "price", WORKDAY(R761+1,-1),1),2,2))
```

**NOTE:**
R761 = 25/08/2020, The R column is for purchase dates

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on (free of sensitive information), in order to reproduce this?

Comment: The formula is only dependent on the R column information that only stores purchase dates in the format above. It's hard to reproduce this issue as it's unpredictable and may start showing itself randomly after you have a bit of data on the spreadsheet.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I'd suggest you to report this via `Help > Report a problem` if you find a way to reliably reproduce this.